# How to correctly set mime-type for Chromium in Django

Tags: django, mime-types, content-type, chromium

In Django, I am serving a png image on the fly as:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
fig_ATF = figure(figsize=(5, 5), facecolor='white')
....
response = HttpResponse(content_type='image/png')
fig_ATF.savefig(response, format='png')
fig_ATF.clear()
response['Content-Length'] = len(response.content)
return response
```

Firefox correctly interprets the *Content-Type* as *image/png*. Chromium, however, does not display the image and complains: *Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html*

These are the relevant response headers in Chromium:

```
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:close
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:20
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 17 Mar 2015 10:08:36 GMT
Expires:Tue, 17 Mar 2015 10:08:37 GMT
Last-Modified:Tue, 17 Mar 2015 10:08:37 GMT
Server:Apache
Vary:Cookie,Accept-Encoding
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
```

**EDIT** The image loads just fine in Chromium when directly accessing it. The problem seems to be related to the fact that it is added with ajax through jQuery:

```
$('#img_location').html('<img src="/path/to/image.png?' + Date.now() + '" width="500" height="500" />');
```

Comment: check the `Response headers` in devtools (F12), under the Network tab.

Comment: @kedar Response headers are now added. I definitively did not zip anything, and content length is way too small even for a zipped image.

Comment: Apache seems to be the culprit here. Using just  the dev server I can't reproduce this issue.

Comment: You are completely right, it works fine with the dev server. Any idea what could be wrong in Apache?

Comment: It depends on how it is configured, apache could be gzipping everything that comes from the django server and not respecting content type.

Comment: The problem might not be with Apache as the image load just fine when directly accessing it in Chromium. However, the problem appears when loading it through ajax, see edit above. I'll investigate if I can find any solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by adding the following line to Apache's httpd.conf:

```
AddType image/png .png
```